# Can I remove all CSS from a webpage?

Tags: css, class, squarespace

I am working with a CMS (SquareSpace) and need all CSS removed from a particular page to start from scratch. Is there something I can put in the CSS that says something to the effect of 'ignore all prior css'?

The problem is there are elements I can't identify or find the class to (such as the header/logo/navigation at the top), and so I think it'd be easier to just start from nothing, because I can't interpret the messy SquareSpace code.

The webpage I'm trying to remove all CSS from is here:

https://jacobmardiphilpott.squarespace.com/google-plays-music-box

Thanks!

Comment: I don't know anything about squarespace, but you can chain more css tags to overwrite the css that is present...

Comment: here's how css specificity works https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity

Answer (score 0):

Tools like [Opera Dragonfly](http://www.opera.com/dragonfly/) or the [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) extension for Firefox can help you identify elements on a web site and styles that are currently assigned to them. In Opera, for example, you it <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd> to open Dragonfly. You can then hover elements with your mouse and get immediate feedback about the elements you are pointing at, their CSS selectors and current styles.